# Странное поведение YII2 при наличии хедера boundary

Tags: yii, yii2

Добрый день, возникла интересная проблема.

Дано: есть YII2 и есть рест апи интерфейс. Отправляем multipart/form-data методом пост на урл и тут начинаются чудеса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как только я убираю boundary, все начинает работать. Однако я хочу его принудительно задать

Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=**X_PAW_BOUNDARY**

При этом даже стандартный вывод контента php отваливается

```
    $rawPost = file_get_contents('php://input');
    var_dump($rawPost); die();
```

Стандартная работа с \YII::$app->request->getRawBody() тоже пуста..

Скажите, что я делаю не так? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак: 
предположим ситуацию, что нам нужно отправить большой multipart запрос с различными данными в одном запросе. Json, XML, файлы. Как действовать в таком случае - самое простое решение (которым пошел и я) это слать rest запрос как multipart/form-data и парсить RAW дату средствами PHP. И это решение работает,  до определенного момента…. Вся штука в том, что как только мы добавляем в заголовки кастомный boundary, мультипрат падает. И как не странно - RAW даты нет ни через php input, ни через  $_POST, $_REQUEST. Перелапатив кучу документации, я понял, что это ошибка не YII фреймворка и даже не PHP. Согласно стандарту  RFC 1341, section 7.2.1 для HTTP, такие сложные запросы должны передаваться как Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p. обратите внимание на MIXED, что означает смешанный